# Server GET json in jersey, JAVA

Tags: java, json, get, jersey

im not sure how to get a json object and output it in jersey using rest GET from a ajax json post, im using grizzly server, server has been set, heres the code that supposed to get the json, correct me please, thanks!

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

import net.sf.json.JSONObject;
import net.sf.json.JSONSerializer;

import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;

import javax.ws.rs.*;

@Path("/helloworld")
public class GetData {
    @GET
    @Consumes("application/json")
            public String getResource(JSONObject obj) throws IOException {

        InputStream in = (InputStream) obj.values();
        String data = IOUtils.toString(in);

        JSONObject out = (JSONObject) JSONSerializer.toJSON(data);

        String result = out.getString("name");
        return result;       


    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to find out, what is your JSON object should be deserialized to. If it's just a JSONObject and you want to parse it manually:

```
@Consumes("application/json")
public String getResource(JSONObject obj) {
...
}
```

If it is some kind of custom object:

```
@Consumes("application/json")
public String getResource(CustomObj customObj) {
...
}
```

But then you should take care about marshalling/unmarshalling of that object to JSON by Jackson.

Comment: ty for the answer! I have a my jquery code here that posts a json to the server

Comment: function sendData() {
    $.ajax({
            url: '/helloworld',
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            data: { json: JSON.stringify({
                name:"Bob",
                ...

            })},
            dataType: 'json'
        });
        alert("json posted!");
    };
so the variable obj contains the json data?

Comment: yes, the object will contain the body of the request - in your case it's the `{ name:"Bob", ... }`

Comment: updated the code in the question now, i try to return the data, but nothing comes out, got following message: ALLVARLIG: A message body reader for Java class net.sf.json.JSONObject, and Java type class net.sf.json.JSONObject, and MIME media type application/octet-stream was not found.